# Minimalist improvement on tiny shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I've just moved into an old (1950's) home.

The only shower is in a tiny bathroom and it's so small that when I take a shower the shower curtain is stuck to one side of my body and the blinds from a window on the other side of the shower are stuck to the other side of my body.

It's very unpleasant, but I don't have the square footage, time, or money to install a new shower.

Is there any easy way to make an improvement?

If nothing else, I'm thinking of restraining the shower curtain with a 2nd rod or something. For some reason (probably related to airflow or temperature, I don't know) the curtain seems to be sucked inward a bit when the shower is turned on.

Comment: When the air in the shower is much warmer than the air outside of the shower, it tends to rise, sucking in the bottom of the shower curtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check on the type of shower curtain they use in hotels that have an arced curtain rod. This would give a slightly more room.

The reason the shower curtain sucks in when you turn the water on probably has to do with hot air rising and pulling in cold air at the bottom of the shower. Try leaving the curtain slightly open at the back of the shower to allow air to enter the shower without pulling the curtain in.

You could also put a layer of opaque material on the window and get rid of the window curtain.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at a solid shower door.

Time and money not withstanding, you could consider changing it into a wet room and get rid of the curtain altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The blinds are easy - translucent window privacy film is available, removable if you change your mind, and sticks to the glass, so that deals with the blinds.

A shower door would be the obvious full-bore solution to the curtain.

Curtain weights (or a weighted curtain) (or, if you happen to get lucky and have a steel/cast iron shower basin, magnets) are a simple approach to the billowing shower curtain. A more rigid/heavier shower curtain (the actual material, as opposed to the added weights at the lower hem) would also help, as it would billow much less.

I find the inner layer of multi-layer shower curtains is particularly prone to fluttering about and being annoying, which is why there are none of those in my house (I meet them in hotels occasionally, and don't like them one bit.)

Comment: Thank you. The privacy film is a very good idea (and I'll see if they have a fully opaque version). The shower door is too big of a project, but I think the other solutions will do.